# Identifying/parsing a very specific cell in CSV file to be used in XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, csv, parsing, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <file>
      <xsl:for-each select="data/row[position()&gt;4 and position()&lt;last()]">
        <record>
            <currency>
              {{this is the point of interest}}
            </currency>
              <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(column5,'',$'','''')" />
              </amount>
            <reference>
              <xsl:value-of select="column1" />
            </reference>
        </record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While this is the CSV file that I'm using:

```
CAD (Canadian Dollar),,,,,,
ACME Inc.,,,,,,
01/01/2019,,,,,,
Reference,Type,From,Date,Due,Status,
REF123,INVOICE,Joe's Furniture,23/01/2019,$123.00,Awaiting,
REF124,INVOICE,Mary's Apparel,6/12/2018,$45.50,Awaiting,
REF125,INVOICE,Bluesy Fashion,29/01/2019,$9,700.00,Awaiting,
REF126,INVOICE,Alice in Wonderland,13/02/2019,$670.07,Awaiting
```

Suppose that I already have a back-end mechanism that can intake a CSV file, then transform it with an XSLT stylesheet. The end transformation is XML.

The goal that I'd like to achieve, here, is to have the **`<currency>`** read the first cell (A1) in the CSV file and extract the first three characters ("CAD", in this case), and then use that value (or whatever it may be).

Comment: Your question is not clear. The input to XSL transformation is XML, not CSV. If you have "a back-end mechanism" that transforms the CSV to XML **before** passing it to XSLT, then show us the XML that is produced.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thank you for clarifying - you are correct. However, I don't have visibility on the pre-XSL XML that you are describing, only the CSV (as shown)

Comment: Use the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) to get it. Without this, you're working blind.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure guess, extrapolating from your XSLT:

```
<currency>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(/data/row[1]/column[1], 1, 3)" />
</currency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is very close, but its not giving me the expected result quite yet.
Since i have the following logic: 
<xsl:for-each select="data/row[position()&gt;4 and position()&lt;last()]"> 
Wouldn't the "/data/row/..." pathway segment only BEGIN reading after the fourth row???

Comment: No, because a path beginning with `/` is an absolute path, independent of the current context.